# CSGO Steam API ~ How to fetch both tradeable and non-tradeable items into array

Tags: php, json

My code is here:

```
case 'get_inv':
        if(!$user) exit(json_encode(array('success'=>false, 'error'=>'You must login to access the deposit.')));
            if((file_exists('cache/'.$user['steamid'].'.txt')) && (!isset($_GET['nocache']))) {
                $array = file_get_contents('cache/'.$user['steamid'].'.txt');
                $array = unserialize($array);
                $array['fromcache'] = true;
                if(isset($_COOKIE['tid'])) {
                    $sql = $db->query('SELECT * FROM `trades` WHERE `id` = '.$db->quote($_COOKIE['tid']).' AND `status` = 0');
                    if($sql->rowCount() != 0) {
                        $row = $sql->fetch();
                        $array['code'] = $row['code'];
                        $array['amount'] = $row['summa'];
                        $array['tid'] = $row['id'];
                        $array['bot'] = "Bot #".$row['bot_id'];
                    } else {
                        setcookie("tid", "", time() - 3600, '/');
                    }
                }
                exit(json_encode($array));
            }
            $prices = file_get_contents('prices.txt');
            $prices = json_decode($prices, true);

            $inv = file_get_contents('https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/'.$user['steamid'].'/inventory/json/730/2/');
            $inv = json_decode($inv, true);
            if($inv['success'] != 1) {
                exit(json_encode(array('error'=>'Your profile is private. Please <a href="http://steamcommunity.com/my/edit/settings" target="_blank">set your inventory to public</a> and <a href="javascript:loadLeft(\'nocache\')">try again</a>.')));
            }
            $items = array();
            foreach ($inv['rgInventory'] as $key => $value) {
                $id = $value['classid'].'_'.$value['instanceid'];
                $trade = $inv['rgDescriptions'][$id]['tradable'];
                if(!$trade) continue;
                $name = $inv['rgDescriptions'][$id]['market_hash_name'];
                $price = $prices['response']['items'][$name]['value']*0.9;
                $img = 'http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/'.$inv['rgDescriptions'][$id]['icon_url'];
                if((preg_match('/(Souvenir)/', $name)) || ($price < $min)) {
                    $price = 0;
                    $reject = 'Junk';
                } else {
                    $reject = 'unknown item';
                }
                $items[] = array(
                    'assetid' => $value['id'],
                    'bt_price' => "0.00",
                    'img' => $img,
                    'name' => $name,
                    'price' => $price,
                    'reject' => $reject,
                    'sa_price' => $price,
                    'steamid' => $user['steamid']);
            }

            $array = array(
                'error' => 'none',
                'fromcache' => false,
                'items' => $items,
                'success' => true);
            if(isset($_COOKIE['tid'])) {
                $sql = $db->query('SELECT * FROM `trades` WHERE `id` = '.$db->quote($_COOKIE['tid']).' AND `status` = 0');
                if($sql->rowCount() != 0) {
                    $row = $sql->fetch();
                    $array['code'] = $row['code'];
                    $array['amount'] = $row['summa'];
                    $array['tid'] = $row['id'];
                    $array['bot'] = "Bot #".$row['bot_id'];
                } else {
                    setcookie("tid", "", time() - 3600, '/');
                }
            }
            file_put_contents('cache/'.$user['steamid'].'.txt', serialize($array), LOCK_EX);
            exit(json_encode($array));
            break;
```

I am trying to get people steam csgo inventory and put into an array. This works perfectly. Could someone help me figure out how to add a not tradeable tag. My plan is to add the item to the array even if not tradeable. I currently have it so if the item isnt worth < $0.30 then call it junk and ignore the press when clicked on. So something like if (!tradable) then mark as "trade locked" and ignore the press. Thank you.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you just want to add another array key named `tradeable` with a boolean value?

Comment: In the same array, I would like items that are not tradeable and are tradable would like the output to look a little like this: https://ibb.co/6sJ1hXQ

Comment: An image of how you're displaying it won't help to construct the solution. Where and how are items identified as tradeable or not? Where and how do you want to store this piece of information about it being tradeable or not?

Comment: It is by the steam api using this link: https://steamcommunity.com/id/2Adept/inventory/json/730/2/ you can pull an inventory status using the variable "market_tradable_restriction":"7" is probably going to be my answer just cant figure out how to implement it.

Comment: Some advice for the future: focus your question on the actual issue. Your question title suggests one problem, your question text another and it turns out what you're really having trouble with is a third thing. This question should be "How to fetch both tradeable and non-tradeable items from CS Go API" and should only show the code that relates to fetching those items (or several versions of the code if you tried different things).